# Backup data from a faulty external hard disk

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive

I'm using a 1TB USB 3.0 HDD from Western Digital. Since last month, the hdd has been so slow that it takes almost 30 minutes for my laptop to recognize the device! Opening a folder is a 10 minute task, and copying a file from the hdd to my laptop happens at 30kbps!! The hdd is almost half filled with data. The WD guys told they can replace the product, but is there any way to backup my data? Are there any tools out there which can read these kind of faulty devices and backup the data?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to remove it from the casing and try it with either another casing or directly connect to a desktop, but I expect this could **void your warranty**.

Failing this, you COULD try with a different operating system ( linux Live CD ) and see if the copy rate is faster. However I wouldnt raise my hopes too much. It doesnt sound like something that software can fix or handle.

Your only hope might be to copy overnight(s).

Comment: This. Remove it from the casing and hook it up to a docking station to get your data back.

Answer (score 0):

I would clone the drive so you have all of its contents.  Use something like CloneZilla or DriveImage XML, both are free.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove casing you can use another adopter but it may void your gaurantee if you feel ther is nothing wrong with hdd board and its a cylnder fault yo could but hard disk in double coated plastic bag or just use 2 plastic bag and carefully check there is no way water gets to it then put the hhard disk in freezer for at least 12 hours then try to recovering the data

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-7591_102-245494/hard-drive-in-freezer-question/
or 
http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux